# vb.net comparing two databases then insert or delete

Tags: database, vb.net

in vb.net how would you loop through database1 to check that all records in database2 exist in Database1 and the other way areound if a record exist in database1 and doesnt exist in database2 then delete it from database1.
so database2 is my reference

how can i do this using queries, also does it have to include nested looping?

note that the records are not in the same order

Thanks

Comment: The best approach depends on what kind of database it is and how many tables are in the database.

Comment: one table and i only care for the value of one column in the comparision which is the name column

Comment: Ah.  Can you link/attach the table in one of the databases from the other database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return all of the rows in the attached table that are not in the local version of the table

```
SELECT * FROM attachedTable 
WHERE col1 NOT IN( SELECT lt.col1 FROM localTable as lt)
```

And this will do the converse, returning all rows in the local table that are not matched in the remote table.

```
SELECT * FROM localTable 
WHERE col1 NOT IN( SELECT rt.col1 FROM attachedTable As rt)
```